# Strange issue with DIV, Setspace, and font in KOMA Class

Tags: spacing, koma-script, setspace, typearea

I am writing a thesis which is almost ready and includes the setspace package like this; `\usepackage{setspace}`
For TOC and references is use singlespacing and onehalfspacing for the rest.
However, I found a rather strange (to me) behavior and it seems to be related to the DIV option in KOMA classes. But only with my non-standard font.

Even if I state `\onehalfspacing` right at the beginning of the document, the result differs if I also call setspace like this: `\usapackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}`

Please see the MWE and enable the onehalfpacing option of setspace:

```
\documentclass[DIV=13,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
%onehalfspacing
]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing strange. If you use option `parskip` in the document preamble, the `\parskip` value is set depending in the `\baselineskip` value while `\begin{document}`. `\baselineskip` depends on whether or not you load `setspace` with or without option `onehalfspacing` or using a command like `\onehalfspacing` in the document preamble. So `\parskip` is different with or without commenting out the option.

Other packages, that are loaded after `setspace` and use `\baselineskip` for the initial value of a length will also produce different results.

For KOMA-Script you can change the behaviour of `parskip` using option `parskip=relative`:

```
\documentclass[DIV=13,parskip=half,parskip=relative]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
%onehalfspacing
]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing
\verb|\parskip|=\the\parskip

\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

But AFAIK their are warnings about using this option at least in the German KOMA-Script book. You can also refresh option `parskip` after changing `\baselineskip`:

```
\documentclass[DIV=13,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
onehalfspacing
]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}
\verb|\parskip|=\the\parskip

\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

BTW: The KOMA-Script manual has some additional information about using `setspace`, e.g., because of changes to the vertical position of headings of ToC, LoF etc. and because of recalculation of the text area and the margins.